# Optimizing C++ code with std::set and shared_ptr

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

Our teacher is teaching us some optimization techniques, and for that she has given us the following C++ code to optimize.

Another point is the overloaded `Add` function, I want to optimized it, but I think its doing its job correctly.

Hence I am confused, where else can I optimize?

Comment: optimize for what? Speed, memory, readability, anything else?

Comment: btw afaik your `emplace` isnt any better than the `push`, you are still first creating the element then move it to the vector. The real power of `emplace` comes when you don't pass the element but only paramters that can be used to construct it in place

Comment: hm...what I gonna say is somehow against c++ teachings and make people angry in a lot of cases :D ....but in your code using `shared_ptr` is not necessary. you can achieve same code with unmanaged pointers which saves you both speed and space. As I said, I sometimes use unmanaged pointers in a code like this.

Comment: It also isn't valid code as-is regardless. `std::shared_ptr` has no member `Get`. Beyond that, there's plenty of places in this code that could be "improved" in one form or another. If the instructions were literally as vacuous as "optimize this code", you need clarification (either provided to you, or us).

Comment: @Afshin exception safety is something you dont get easily with manually managed raw pointers. smart pointers is more than just not forgetting to `delete`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I know. As I said in his code. smart pointers surely have several benefits and it should be used by default, but sometimes people over use smart pointers. at least in this code `shared_ptr` is overkilling. he can achieve same this with `unique_ptr`. if he could handle exceptions, he can use normal unmanged pointer too. people should understand what is effects of a smart pointer when they use it, like when they try unmanaged pointers. but this part is forgotten from mindset of a lot of people.

Comment: My advice is to always try to use `std::unique_ptr`, and only use `std::shared_ptr` when you absolutely have to (which can approach *never*).  And only use a *raw pointer* as a non-owning pointer.  If you need a container of things, use `std::vector<Thing>`, and if the things are polymorphic `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Thing>>`.

Comment: What are the criteria for optimisation?    Memory usage?  Speed?   Exception safety?   Maintainability of code?   Readability of the code to a human?   Lines of code?   Cyclomatic complexity?   Minimising number of dynamically allocated objects that are created and destroyed?       Depending on your choice of criteria, some approaches may be completely reasonable, some may be completely unreasonable, and some won't matter squat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FStructA` and `FStructB` share a common member `Key`, so maybe consider moving that to a base class they both derive from.

When dealing with polymorphic types, the base class almost always needs a `virtual` destructor, so that derived constructors are called correctly when destroying an object via a base class pointer. This is especially important when using smart pointers, such as in containers of polymorphic objects, as this code is doing.

`struct` members are `public` by default, and a `struct` derives from another `struct` using `public` inheritance by default, so explicitly stating `FStructA` and `FStructB` inherit `public`ly from `IStruct` is redundant.

When using `override`, you don't need to specify `virtual` again. `override` implies `virtual` by its very nature.

Avoid using `new`  with smart pointer constructors. Use `std::make_...()` functions instead - `std::make_unique()` for `std::unique_ptr`, and `std::make_shared()` for `std::shared_ptr()`.

The overloaded `Add()` methods can be merged together into a single template method.

`emplace_back()` is the same as `push_back()` when dealing with (smart) pointers, especially with polymorphic types that have to be constructed outside of the container.  Using `emplace_back()` rather than `push_back()` makes sense only when the container itself is able to construct the elements directly, then you simply give `emplace_back()` the constructor parameters. But that is not the case in this code.

In your `range-for` loop, you are taking `DataElement` *by value*, which will make a copy of each `shared_ptr` in `DataElements`, thus incrementing and decrementing their reference counts as they enter and leave scope.  While that is fine, it is needless overhead. You should take `DataElement` by reference instead. In fact, when iterating any container, you should typically use references, unless you really need copies, or the overhead of making copies is negligible (ie, with trivial types).

Consider using `auto` whenever possible when declaring variables, especially when dealing with template types. This is particularly useful in `range-for` loops.

Don't use `static_cast` with the raw pointer of a `shared_ptr`, use `static_pointer_cast` instead to maintain proper shared ownership semantics.

Don't make copies of an object unnecessarily. You are dereferencing the result of `static_cast`, then making a copy of the object, and then you are processing the copy, not the original. This can be useful at times, but this code is not one of them. Use a pointer or reference to avoid the copy.

Don't cast a base class to a derived class unless you really need to. If you have polymorphic types (as this code does), prefer to use polymorphic behavior (ie, virtual methods) whenever possible. Proper polymorphic processing logic should not care what types it is operating on.

Don't use `std::shared_ptr` when `std::unique_ptr` will suffice. `std::shared_ptr` has overhead (reference counting, control block, etc) that `std::unique_ptr` does not have.  Shared ownership has its uses, but this code does not exhibit them.

With that said, try something more like this:

```cpp
struct IStruct
{
    std::string Key;
    virtual ~IStruct() = default;
    //virtual bool GetType() const = 0;
    virtual void Process() = 0;
};

struct FStructA : IStruct
{
    int IntData;

    /*
    bool GetType() const override
    {
        return true;
    }
    */

    void Process() override
    {
        // Process A
    }
};

struct FStructB : IStruct
{
    float FloatData;

    /*
    bool GetType() const override
    {
        return false;
    }
    */

    void Process() override
    {
        // Process B
    }
};

class SomeSystem
{
public:
    template<typename T, typename... Args>
    void Add(Args&&... args)
    {
        DataElements.push_back(/*std::make_shared*/std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    }

    void Process()
    {
        for (auto &DataElement : DataElements)
        {
            /*
            if (DataElement->GetType())
            {
                auto StructA = static_pointer_cast<FStructA>(DataElement);
                // Process A
            }
            else
            {
                auto StructB = static_pointer_cast<FStructB>(DataElement);
                // Process B
            }
            */

            DataElement->Process();
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector</*std::shared_ptr*/std::unique_ptr<IStruct>> DataElements;
};

int main()
{
    SomeSystem system;
    system.Add<FStructA>(...params as needed...);
    system.Add<FStructB>(...params as needed...);
    system.Process();
}
```